# Question that needs a selection

Tags: terminology, questions

What do you call a question that needs a selection? For example:

> Is an argument true until proven false or vice-versa?

Answer (score 2):

I'd call that an "either-or" question, or if there are more than two choices, a "multiple-choice" question.

Answer (score 2):

A question that invites the reader to choose one of two propositions, especially where those propositions are mutually exclusive, might be called a ***dichotomous question***.

A dichotomous question might require a yes or no response, which would make it a [closed-ended question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-ended_question) but a defining attribute of a dichotomy is that it poses two choices, or "selections" to use your word.